I can't get Azure Application Proxy to work with a ASP.NET Core app. What am I doing wrong?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and created a new ASP.NET Core MVC web app using C#. I am able to get the app registered in Azure and it is authenticating correctly. Everything seems to be working locally and if I publish the app to the IIS dev server to a url like https://DEVSERVERNAME:2212/, it works there too.
My problem is when I publish it to the production server (IIS). I bind it to http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/ and then go into Azure to setup the Application proxy. The proxy URL is https://appproxydotnetcoretest-companyname.msappproxy.net/. The internal url is http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/.
When I browse to the app proxy URL it redirects to the Microsoft authentication page but when it redirects back to goes to http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/ and not the proxy URL. I have no issues getting this working with .NET Framework but I can't seem to get it working for .NET Core.
My Program.cs file has not changed since it was generated when the app was created. My appsettings.json file is as follows:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "CompanyName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "2bxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx65",
    "ClientId": "cfxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx35",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "vDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxnm"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}

Update: This is the error I get when browsing to the application proxy URL:
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'cf77c6a2-1ec8-4b55-8b27-6d9dc196c735'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.
This is what is setup in Azure App registration Authentication Redirect URIs:
http://localhost:5239/signin-oidc
https://localhost:7090/signin-oidc
https://localhost:44372/signin-oidc 
http://localhost:52128/signin-oidc
https://DEVSERVERNAME:2212/signin-oidc
https://appproxydotnetcoretest-companyname.msappproxy.net/


What the redirect url is in your azure portal ? https://appproxydotnetcoretest-companyname.msappproxy.net/  or https://SERVERNAME:2212/ ?

When the app was created VS added the following:
http://localhost:5239/signin-oidc https://localhost:7090/signin-oidc https://localhost:44372/signin-oidc http://localhost:52128/signin-oidc I added this for the dev server: https://SERVERNAME:2212/signin-oidc The App Proxy added this: https://appproxydotnetcoretest-companyname.msappproxy.net/

The error message is straightforward: your AAD/Entra's configured allowed-redirect-URIs does not contain http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/signin-oidc - so you need to add it - and then it will work.

What is supposed to happen is after it authenticates with Microsoft it should redirect  back to the app proxy URL https://appproxydotnetcoretest-companyname.msappproxy.net/. In .NET Framework the Web.config allows you to provide a RedirectUri but in .NET Core you can't. The other issue is I can't add http://PRODSERVERNAME:2212/ to the Redirect URIs because it isn't HTTPS.

@JeffCraft In ASP.NET Core you specify the redirect URI in the UseOpenIdConnect or similar method in your Startup/Configure/ConfigureServices - or in your appsettings.json file - or in a new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = ... } whenever/whereever you do that.
